# Django queryset from url parameter issue

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have multi models, and I want to have one listview to display it.

I would like to have something like this:

```
model = self.kwargs['name']
queryset = model.objects.all()
```

but seems not working....

any help please ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.get_object_for_this_type) for this

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=self.kwargs['app_label'], model=self.kwargs['name'])
model = content_type.model_class()
queryset = model.objects.all()
```

Comment: not working, the error is : django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your "model" variable is a string.  You can't just use a string to use functions of model class.  You need get the model class first.

```
from django.apps import apps

model = apps.get_model('app_name', self.kwargs['name'])
queryset = model.objects.all()
```